# Is it possible to store types, not instances of those types, in a Vec?

Tags: generics, reflection, rust

Is it possible to store different Rust types into a `Vec` in some form that would allow me to get the types at later date?

I could store the `TypeId` of any types, but I couldn't then use the `TypeId` to get back to the original types, as far as I know.

In Java terms, I want to create a `[boolean.class, char.class, ...]`, etc.

Comment: What do you want to do with the types later?

Comment: ^ and... have you looked into traits?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: I have a heterogeneous list, that I want to type check. I used some type shenanigans to have all it's values in `Vec<Box<Any>>`, but extracting the types gets a bit... hard and I assume slow since the type is essentially a `Cons<i32, Cons<bool, Nil>>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by typechecking a heterogenous list, and extracting types.  Can you show some pseudo code for what you want to do?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, although not sure what you **exactly** mean? Storing different traits in Vector instead of types?

Comment: Agree with @ChrisEmerson, but perhaps **not** by changing *this* question, as it already has two answers for the current phrasing.

Comment: @DanielFath: You need something homogeneous in a `Vec`, but types could implement a single `trait` that returns what kind of type is stored in it (if the list of kind if finite) or you could use an `enum` if the list of types/kinds is well-known in advance, etc... You may want to ask a new question presenting the code you have written with `Cons` and asking how to do it better: with an exact example of your problem, the answers will be more relevant.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit hard to explain. But imagine you have `let x = Cons<32, Cons<true, Cons<"string", Nil>>>` and you want to extract the `"string"` from it. I was hoping to extract the type from a paired vector of types, rather than search recursively.

Answer (score 6):

No. Types are not a runtime construct and are removed during compilation. You cannot have a collection of the types themselves because they don't exist.

Most of the time, you want to [create a heterogeneous collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423) that all adhere to some shared interface (a.k.a. a `trait`).

Answer (score 4):

The only reason that `Integer.class` is useful in Java, is because Java implements *reflection*:

- the runtime has a description of all existing types
- for each type, it has a description of all attributes and methods

and therefore the virtual machine can, at runtime, create an instance of a type *from thin air*.

---

Automatic, pervasive reflection violates at least one core tenet of Rust:

> You don't pay for what you don't use.

so has not been implemented.

Rust has *some amount* of reflection still:

- it has compile-time reflection, via plugins
- it has some type information, via `TypeId`

However, the former does not incur any memory/performance overhead and the latter is on a pay-per-use basis.

As far as I know, there is no proposal to significantly extend reflection yet. Even down-casting is for now explored as a library, and not a language, option (see the [query_interface](https://docs.rs/query_interface/0.3.3/query_interface/) crate).