# Is it possible to have a heterogeneous vector of types that implement Eq?

Tags: rust

I want a vector for elements that contain a trait such as `Eq` and I need heterogeneous vectors. For example:

```
let mut x: Vec<Eq> = Vec::new();

x.push(1);
x.push("hello")
```

I get an error message that says that `Eq` cannot be made into an object:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `std::cmp::Eq` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:2:20
  |
2 |     let mut x: Vec<Eq> = Vec::new();
  |                    ^^ the trait `std::cmp::Eq` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot use `Self` as a type parameter in the supertrait listing
```

Is it possible to have a list of pointers to things I can compare regardless of their types?

Comment: If you're happy to use the `Any` trait instead of `Eq` specifically, `Vec<Box<Any>>` works ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=22fcc82ccea3f0b0aa0f3528f23d35a6&version=stable&backtrace=0)).

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to be able to compare the things in the vector though.

In particular, the larger problem, is that I would like to have a HashMap with heterogeneous keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a list of pointers to things I can compare regardless of their types?

This doesn't make sense. How do you "compare" a `String` and a `File` or a `Socket` and a `GuiWindowFontFamily`?

The code has some minor issues as well, namely that it lacks any kind of indirection for the trait. See [What is the best way to create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects) for a good overview of how to make a heterogeneous vector when not fighting object safety.

Speaking of *object safety*, [there's a great blog series on the subject](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/), which covers the details of the specific error you are getting.

So, what can we do? For starters, we can be more specific:

```
let mut x: Vec<Box<PartialEq<u8>>> = Vec::new();
```

This works because we are saying that everything in the vector can be compared to a `u8`, and there's not an open-ended infinite number of possibilities that each may be compared to.

You could also implement some trait that dictates how things should be compared, and then use that:

```
trait Silly {
    fn silly(&self) -> usize;
}

impl Silly for u8 {
    fn silly(&self) -> usize { *self as usize }
}

impl Silly for bool {
    fn silly(&self) -> usize { 1 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: Vec<Box<Silly>> = Vec::new();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Comparing things of different type is very simple, values of different type are always different, however, values of the same type can be equal.
In my case, what I am trying to implement is an n-ary tree, where each level has a different type of keys, so I need that the generic type parameter to be somewhat general, and I totally need Eq and Hash.

Comment: @FCo What key types are we speaking of? Can't you wrap them around an enum?

Comment: An enum is an excellent solution, IMO. Then it's up to the user of the data structure to implement `Eq` as appropriate.

Comment: I liked the idea  of the enum, it lead me to the ultimate solution that was keep each level of the tree as its own separate data structure. The overcomplicated and difficult to type heterogeneous key tree was the wrong approach.