# Equality comparison of primitives through an Eq trait

Tags: rust

I have a struct, and ultimately I'd like to be able to access the fields of this struct through a hash for the purposes of comparing individual fields equality with other instances of the same setup.

The documentation for the `Eq` trait seems to say that `Eq` is implemented for the primitive types (`u8`, `i16`, etc.). My goal is to store references to `Eq` in a map and then do equality comparison through them.

```
struct User {
    id: u32,
    age: u8,
    fingers: u8,
    toes: u8,
}

let u1 = User { id: 1234, age: 42, fingers: 10, toes: 10 };
let u2 = User { id: 5678, age: 41, fingers: 10, toes: 10 };

let mut umap1: HashMap<String, &dyn Eq> = HashMap::new();
//                             ^^^^^^^ - Wrong... but I don't know if this is even possible.
```

What I'd like to do is insert into the hash something like:

```
umap1["id"] = &u1.id
umap1["age"] = &u1.age
```

I could then have a second hash (`umap2`) and do something like this:

```
if umap1["id"] == umap2["id"]
```

Possible?

I believe [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423) is not really the same thing because it testing for equality between enums. I'd like to be able to take an `Eq` reference to a primitive type (like a `u16`, etc.) and compare it to another.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Why do you believe that enums are materially different from a "primitive"? What error did you get when when you tried the solution before posting your update?

Comment: Well, for one the method linked to requires deriving a trait for a new type (the enum)... I don't think I should have to change the types of all of the members of my struct.

Comment: In that case, what do you think about [Is it possible to have a heterogeneous vector of types that implement Eq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40411045/155423)? Your hash can stand in for the vector in the question. The OP there even said *I would like to have a HashMap with heterogeneous keys*.

Comment: `String` also implements `Eq`; does that mean you can compare a `String` to a `u16`?

Comment: Well, I don't want to do that... I am only interested in Equality comparing objects of the same type... Since it looks like Eq is implemented for all the primitive types I had hoped this meant that I could store references to Eq in a map.

Comment: So... what do you expect to happen if you *do* write something like `umap1["id"] == umap2["age"]`? Panic? Or what `impl Eq` block do you think would apply there?

Comment: `Eq` doesn't actually let you do anything, for the record -- `PartialEq` is the trait that provides the `==` operator. `Eq` just requires `PartialEq<Self>`.