# Storing struct without defining the generic types in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm coming to Rust from a background of Java, C#, C++, as well as limited C knowledge. I switched to Rust because I thought the design patterns and the type safety would greatly improve my final product. I'm not great at writing these kinds of things, so I've made a list of my goals and the problem I am having.

Goals:

- I want a `Vec` or any list that stores different objects that implement a common trait.

  - The trait has two generic types that are defined by the object that implements it.
- Each object stored in the list would be unique, meaning the object would have unique objects defined for the implementation of the trait.
- Each unique object should only be in the list once.
- I would like to keep track of the generic types associated with each object. This is not my current problem nor am I worried about this detail right now, but I will not turn down advice for this.

I'm not sure what the best/safest way to store a generic type with a generic trait while still having the flexibility I would like.

```
// common functions in trait that use A and B.
pub trait Common<A, B> {
    fn common_behavior_one(a: A) {}
    fn common_behavior_two(b: B) {}
}

// these are example objects and there would be many more sets like this
struct objectA {}
struct objectB {}
struct CommonObject {} // stores list of objectA's and consumes objectB's

impl Common<objectA, objectB> for CommonObject {
    fn common_behavior_one(a: objectA) {}
    fn common_behavior_two(b: objectB) {}
}

//this is where my problem starts
struct Manager {
    // i would like this to accept any Object with the Common trait implemented
    // regardless of what the generics for the trait are.
    objects: Vec<Box<impl Common>>, // problem
}

impl Manager {
    pub fn add_object<A, B>(&mut self, _object: Box<Common<A, B>>) { // potential problem
        // add _object to vec
    }

    pub fn remove_object<A, B>(&mut self, _object: Box<Common<A, B>>) { // potential problem
        // remove _object from vec
    }

    pub fn get_object() {} // not sure about how im going to do this.

    pub fn pass_to_object<B>(&mut self, _struct: Box<B>) { // potential problem
        // pass _struct(B type) into common where it will be consumed.
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [Is it possible to have a heterogeneous vector of types that implement Eq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40411045/155423);