# Store a collection of heterogeneous types with generic type parameters in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a basic [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) in Rust. I want a data structure storing, for each component, a storage of that particular component. Because some components are common while others are rare, I want different types of storage policies such as `VecStorage<T>` and `HashMapStorage<T>`.

As components are unknown to the game engine's ECS, I came up with:

```
trait AnyStorage: Debug {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct StorageMgr {
    storages: HashMap<TypeId, Box<AnyStorage>>,
}
```

with `VecStorage` and `HashMapStorage<T>` implementing the `AnyStorage` trait. Since `AnyStorage` doesn't know `T`, I added one more trait implemented by both concrete storages: `ComponentStorage<T>`.

While I was able to register new components (i.e. add a new `Box<AnyStorage>` in `StorageMgr`'s `storages`), I didn't find a way to insert components.

Here is the erroneous code:

```
pub fn add_component_to_storage<C: Component>(&mut self, component: C) {
    let storage = self.storages.get_mut(&TypeId::of::<C>()).unwrap();
    // storage is of type: &mut Box<AnyStorage + 'static>

    println!("{:?}", storage); // Prints "VecStorage([])"

    storage.insert(component); // This doesn't work

    // This neither:
    // let any_stor: &mut Any = storage;
    // let storage = any_stor.downcast_ref::<ComponentStorage<C>>();
}
```

I know that my problem comes from the fact that `storage`'s type is `&mut Box<AnyStorage>`; can I obtain the concrete `VecStorage` from it?

The whole point of doing all this is that I want components to be contiguous in memory and to have different storage for each component type.  I can not resolve myself to use `Box<Component>`, or I don't see how.

I reduced my problem to a minimal code [on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=58aefba48b9d35d636a44afd12eb85df&version=stable).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why it's not a duplicate of [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster because of the word "generic". I know how to create a heterogeneous collection and how to use polymorphism in Rust, but not with genericity. Should I add this as an introductory paragraph?

Comment: @totorigolo That is not possible. Trait objects cannot have generic type parameters, because these are resolved in compile time. The usual way of going around that is to use/manipulate the contained objects through another common trait for all components. That, or forget heterogeneity and use concrete types (as in, multiple containers for each type, or an enum type for the components).

Comment: @E_net4 Thanks for your clarification. But I realize that the title of my question is very unclear. What I want to do isn't _stricto sensus_ a collection of heterogeneous generics: that's what is the `StorageMgr` from a macro view. (I can't put it clearly, sorry)
I wrote a common trait, `AnyStorage`, as you suggest, and I'm sure there is a way to get my `VecStorage` back since `println!("{:?}", storage);` prints `VecStorage([])`.

Comment: You can only do that because you added the `Debug` constraint to `AnyStorage`. It sounds like you want to have the method `insert` in `AnyStorage`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wasn't sure if something like this was possible but I've finally figured it out. There are a couple things to note as to why your posted example was failing.

1. Trait `AnyStorage` in your example did not implement `ComponentStorage<T>`, therefore because you were storing your "storage"s in a `HashMap<TypeId, Box<AnyStorage>>`, Rust could not guarantee that every stored type implemented `ComponentStorage<T>::insert()` because it only knew that they were `AnyStorage`s.
2. If you did combine the two traits into one simply called `Storage<T>` and stored them in a `HashMap<TypeId, Box<Storage<T>>`, every version of `Storage` would have to store the same type because of the single `T`. Rust doesn't have a way to dynamically type the values of a map based on the TypeId of the key, as a solution like this would require. Also, you can't replace `T` with `Any` because `Any` isn't `Sized`, which `Vec` and all other storage types require. I'm guessing you knew all of this which is why you used two different traits in your original example.

The solution I ended up using stored the `Storage<T>`s as `Any`s in a `HashMap<TypeId, Box<Any>>`, and then I downcasted the `Any`s into `Storage<T>`s inside the implementation functions for `StorageMgr`. I've put a short example below, and a full version is on Rust Playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c28337253e0ca3e6188cd0bd391e9f42&version=nightly)
.

```
trait Component: Debug + Sized + Any {
    type Storage: Storage<Self>;
}

trait Storage<T: Debug>: Debug + Any {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;

    fn insert(&mut self, value: T);
}

struct StorageMgr {
    storages: HashMap<TypeId, Box<Any>>,
}

impl StorageMgr {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            storages: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_storage_mut<C: Component>(&mut self) -> &mut <C as Component>::Storage {
        let type_id = TypeId::of::<C>();

        // Add a storage if it doesn't exist yet
        if !self.storages.contains_key(&type_id) {
            let new_storage = <C as Component>::Storage::new();

            self.storages.insert(type_id, Box::new(new_storage));
        }

        // Get the storage for this type
        match self.storages.get_mut(&type_id) {
            Some(probably_storage) => {
                // Turn the Any into the storage for that type
                match probably_storage.downcast_mut::<<C as Component>::Storage>() {
                    Some(storage) => storage,
                    None => unreachable!(), // <- you may want to do something less explosive here
                }
            }
            None => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
```