# How to store types with varying parameters in a Vec?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to set up a tree structure in Rust, but I've run into an issue with how to store the list of nodes, which store different types of values, and therefore have different type parameters.

A simplified version of the problem is below:

```
struct Node<T> {
    pub props: T,
    pub children: Vec<Node>
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node {
        props: (42, 6),
        children: vec![Node {
            props: Some("potatoes"),
            children: vec![]
        }]
    };
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:4:19
  |
4 |     children: Vec<Node>
  |                   ^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

I can't provide a type argument, since it must be allowed to be anything.  What's the best way to go about doing this?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423), but it doesn't address type arguments.

Comment: It would *seem* like it would implicitly require a second type parameter, say `Q`, such that the children of `Node<T, Q>` are `Node<Q>`, but then... Would an associated type be the answer? No, because associated types are for traits...

Comment: Hang on. "store different types of values, and therefore have different type parameters." Provided I'm reading that right, unless they're [Trait Objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html), that wouldn't fly in a statically typed language liked Rust.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why the answers to [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423) don't answer your question.

Comment: The duplicate does indeed address your question: your type argument `T` can be monomorphised into a `Box<Props>`: `Node<Box<Props>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store different types of values, first ascertain what are all the types of values you would want to store.
Then define an `enum` as such:

```
enum Value {
    Pair(i32, i32),
    MayBeStr(Option<&'static str>),
    ... // any value that you would like to store
}
```

And wire it up like:

```
struct Node {
    pub props: Value,
    pub children: Vec<Node>
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node {
        props: Value::Pair(42, 6),
        children: vec![Node {
            props: Value::MayBeStr(Some("potatoes")),
            children: vec![]
        }]
    };
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8ab0a27fa2445dd5037907311a840441&version=stable)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a finite number of types to store, otherwise I would do it that way

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up with so far is to add a trait to all the items and use Boxes to store them.  For this example:

```
trait Props {}

impl Props for (i32, i32) {}
impl<'a> Props for Option<&'a str> {}

struct Node<'a> {
    pub props: Box<Props + 'a>,
    pub children: Vec<Node<'a>>
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node {
        props: Box::new((42, 6)),
        children: vec![Node {
            props: Box::new(Some("potatoes")),
            children: vec![]
        }]
    };
}
```

Comment: But how do you get the value back?

Comment: That, I'm not sure about