# Taking equal-sized chunks from multiple audio streams in Rust in parallel

Tags: audio, rust, parallel-processing, signal-processing, audio-channels

I'm trying to write elegant audio processing code in Rust that can consume chunks of audio from N channels (mono, stereo or surround, known at compile-time) in lock-step, reduce them and send the reduced value (or flat-mapped value) off to another stream for processing.

In Clojure, the sequence abstractions and higher-order transducers make it easy to bite chunks off a stream and post a processed result to another `core.async` channel, but I'm struggling to get this working in Rust, especially since Rust complains about generic iterators not being sized at compile time.

Specifically, how do I consume equal-sized chunks of audio from multiple channels in lock-step, to e.g. calculate the summed square of all values, and then do something with that value? I'm aware of crossbeam.

Here is the pseudo-code I'm reaching for:

```
type AudioSample = f64;
struct Signal<S, const N: usize> {
    sample_rate: f64,
    channels: [Iterator<S>; N], // I know this won't compile
}

fn process_signal(signal: Signal<AudioSample, 5>) -> f64 {
    let mut sum_squared = 0.0;
    let chunk_size = 0.1 * signal.sample_rate; // 100ms of audio from each channel
    for channel in signal.channels {  // how to parallelize this blocking call?
        let chunk = channel.take(chunk_size); // assuming this blocks until 100ms of signal is available
        sum_squared += chunk.fold(|0., sample| sample * sample);
    }

    sum_squared
}
```

Bonus points if you can show a pragmatic way to make the **`process_signal()`** function "incremental", i.e. asynchronous and parallelizable for N-channels.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact ? not clear what you want

Comment: Since you mention parallelize and blocking calls: do you expect the "iterators" to be receiving data from another thread while you are pulling data from them, or is all this single-threaded?

Comment: I expect it would have to be multi-threaded, but it would be pretty cool if it could be single-threaded, assuming there is a way to peek/select at N buffers that are being populated by a hardware interrupt.

Comment: @Stargateur I want to consolidate N channels in parallel by taking equal-sized chunks from N audio channels, map over those chunks and reduce them to a single value which gets sent off for processing elsewhere. Any concrete solution to that general problem will do. Extra bonus points if N does not need to be known at compile-time.

Comment: I've now found this DSP crate, which might be more appropriate for what I'm trying to do - haven't tried yet, though: http://rustaudio.github.io/dsp-chain/dsp/

Comment: @PetrusTheron How about losing a bit performance, yet being able to both **avoid blocking** + **run concurrently** (a true-[PARALLEL] process-flow is not possible(or rather is an anti-pattern for cases)where asynchronous,potentially blocking inputs dis-coordinate otherwise potentially true-[PARALLEL] processes). A per-channel *parallel*, principally non-blocking loop, .poll()-only pre-testing,if anything arrived and just reading if ready-to-read input channel byte-by-byte, producing sum_squared fully ***incrementally***,as the chunking logic/windowing now becomes controlled in my loop code.

Comment: Not a Rust-specific approach, yet working this way in high-performance, low-latency, non-blocking multi-channel processing distributed-system designs, where each locally-processed channel has also a different priority and different payload-processing. Byte-sized reading may seem awfully on a first look, yet may help in deterministic sizing for compile-time, may help avoid both the blocking and other problems with skewed synchronicity / slippage / jitter / temporal LoS / {source|transport}-failure-detection / spurious events / flooding ingress.

Comment: *especially since Rust complains about generic iterators not being sized* — [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423)

Comment: *to another `core.async` channel* — are you aware that iterators are not the equivalent to this? You want [futures](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-rs/) / streams.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can have another thread responsible for processing, rather than try to synchronize buffer reads? This seems like a nice opportunity to use [a mpsc channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html).

Since you'll likely only be able to react to the callback from the audio scheduler being called, it's worry you'll spend a lot of time waiting/blocking for buffers to be ready if you try to for processing to happen in unison.