# Rust special array

Tags: arrays, rust, nested-lists, heterogeneous-array

I want to define function that takes one argument which is "special" array, like in example below:

`[5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]]`

This array is a non-empty array that contains either integers or other "special" arrays.

What should be the proper argument type of the function that receives such "special" array?

Comment: This is called heterogeneous array, and impossible with this syntax. Use either an enum or a trait object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot give an array like that as a parameter to a function, because it is ot homogeneous. However, you can define your own type of special array.

The following code shows how to encode a special array **[2, [2, 2]]**:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Special {
    Integer(i32),
    Vector(Vec<Special>)
}

fn main() {
    let special = Special::Vector(
        vec![Special::Integer(2), 
        Special::Vector(vec![Special::Integer(2), Special::Integer(2)])]
    );
    println!("{:?}", special);
}
```

You can use pattern matching to check on which kind of enum element you have in the array, either an **Integer** or a **Vector**:

```
match special {
    Special::Integer(val) => println!("I am an integer: {}", val),
    Special::Vector(vec) => println!("I have nested element inside: {:?}", vec)
}
```

To iterate through such an array you need a function that can evaluate reccursively, because the **Vector** arm has nestef elements. We can define a function that evals reccursively as such:

```
fn eval(special: Special) {
    match special {
        Special::Integer(val) => println!("Integer met {}", val),
        Special::Vector(vec) => vec.into_iter().for_each(|special_elem| eval(special_elem))
    }
}
```

One thing worth noticing is that since we capture by value, we cause a move, so we can safely use **into_iter** to make sure we consume all the values.

Comment: I bet we could even define a `special!` macro to allow the syntax given in the question.

Comment: You can define a macro that evaluates such an expression. I know for sure it's possible, but if you want to pass the array to some functions, I think it has to be defined as an enum or you need to create a type that respects some trait bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I iterate through this kind of array? Do I need to implement something else in order to do so?

Comment: @cdhowie We can if the arrays are literals.

Comment: @NeNe I have edited my answer with an eval fn