# Can I use the "null pointer optimization" for my own non-pointer types?

Tags: optimization, rust

When you have an `Option<&T>`, the compiler knows that `NULL` is never a possible value for `&T`, and [encodes the `None` variant as `NULL` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16504643/155423). This allows for space-saving:

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<&u8>(), mem::size_of::<Option<&u8>>());
}
```

However, if you do the same with a non-pointer type, there's no extra bits to store that value in and extra space is required:

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    // fails because left is 1 and right is 2
    assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<u8>(), mem::size_of::<Option<u8>>()); 
}
```

In general, this is correct. However, I'd like to opt-in to the optimization because I know that my type has certain impossible values. As a made-up-example, I might have a player character that has an age. The age may be unknown, but will never be as high as `255`:

```
struct Age(u8);

struct Player {
    age: Option<Age>,
}
```

I'd like to be able to inform the optimizer of this constraint - `Age` can never be `255`, so it's safe to use that bit pattern as `None`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of Rust 1.28, you can use [`std::num::NonZeroU8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroU8.html) (and friends).  This acts as a wrapper that tells the compiler the contents of a number will *never* contain a literal zero.  It's also why `Option<Box<T>>` is pointer-sized.

Here's an example showing how to create an `Age` and read its payload.

```
use std::num::NonZeroU8;

struct Age(NonZeroU8);

impl Age {
    pub fn new(age: u8) -> Age {
        let age = NonZeroU8::new(age).expect("Age cannot be zero!");
        Age(age)
    }

    pub fn age(&self) -> u8 {
        self.0.get()
    }
}

struct Player {
    age: Option<Age>,
}

fn main() {
    println!("size: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Player>());
    // Output: size: 1
}
```

Comment: Going by the name, I'm assuming that `NonZero` disallows zero values. What about values other than zero? In my example, zero might be valid, but 255 is not.

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's hardcoded to non-0, I suppose with a trait and associated constants one could extend this... however for now you'll have to settle for mathematics. If 255 is your magic value, then applying a `+1` going to storage and `-1` coming from storage (with wrapping arithmetic) will suffice for the `NonZero` magic to work :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. certainly, I'll just have to do more profiling to see if it's truly worth it. Using less bytes seems like an obvious win; using less bytes *and* mandatory math everywhere is less sure-fire.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Certainly; although, with 0 being an oft-used magic value, a good number of branching instructions are specialized for it (`jz` and `jnz` come to mind), so it's unclear whether an associated constant could beat that.

Comment: BTW `NonZeroU*` will be stabilized in 1.28.

Comment: `NonZero` also doesn't help if you have more than one sentinel value. It's pretty common to have two or three.