# Translate performance critical loop from C to Rust

Tags: c, rust, translate

I'm experimenting with rewriting some old C code into Rust - which I'm new to. One recurring issue I have is that the C code has a lot of loops like this:

```c
for (i = startIndex; i < asize; i++)   
{
    if (firstEdge < 0 && condLeft(i))
    {
        firstEdge = i;
    }

    RightIndex = asize-1-i;
    if (firstEdgeRight < 0 && condRight(RightIndex))
    {
        firstEdgeRight = RightIndex;
    }

    // Found both edges
    if (firstEdge >= 0 && firstEdgeRight >= 0) {
        break;  
    }
}
```

How would you translate that into Rust in a performant way? My issue is that while I could probably get the functionality I want I'm not sure how to do it obtain (roughly) the same speed.

This part of the code is the main bottleneck in our code (this part of the code at least) and when translating it would like to keep the following properties.

1. The loop should break ASAP since `asize` can be very large.
2. Both `firstEdge` and `firstEdgeRight` are found roughly at the same time. Therefore it has been a good thing to only have one loop instead of two - in order to avoid search from the beginning again (even though I think this solution kills the prefetcher (but I'm not sure, maybe the old machine running the code doesn't even have a prefetcher)).

While performance is important, readability is of course even more important :)

**EDIT** Ok, here is a possible Rust implementation by me (`cond_right()` and `cond_left()` are left out).
The things I think about is:

1. Is this how other people would write it if they had to implement it from scratch?
2. Do I really need to make `first_edge` and `first_edge_right` mutable? They are in my implementation, but it feels wrong to me since they are only assigned once.

```rust
let mut first_edge = -1;
let mut first_edge_right = -1;

// Find first edge

let start_index = 300; // or something
let asize = 10000000;

for i in start_index..asize {
    if first_edge < 0 && cond_left(i) {
        first_edge = i;
    }

    let right_index = asize - i -1;
    if first_edge_right < 0 && cond_right(right_index) {
        first_edge_right = right_index;
    }

    if (first_edge >= 0 && first_edge_right >= 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you already tried. Also you did neither specify types nor start values, that makes the solution space quite amusing, but not useful to you.

Comment: As ker noted, please provide a **Rust** example; even a naive translation is fine as long as it compiles and is functionally correct. Rust supports the `break` statement and can iterate over integer ranges, so it seems that it has everything you need...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've added my naïve implementation, but I do have some questions about it. And I was really hoping to see how a more experienced Rust programmer would implement the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be prepared to make a choice:

1. > How would you translate that into Rust in a performant way?
2. > while performance is important, readability is of course even more important

Which is actually more important to you? Here's how I would write the code, assuming that I've understood what you are asking for:

```
fn left_condition(i: usize) -> bool {
    i > 1000
}

fn right_condition(i: usize) -> bool {
    i % 73 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let start_index = 300;
    let asize = 10000000;

    let left = (start_index..asize).position(left_condition);
    let right = (start_index..asize).rev().position(right_condition);

    println!("{:?}, {:?}", left, right);
}
```

We iterate once from left-to-right and once from right-to-left. My *gut* tells me that this will provide code with simple branch prediction that accesses memory in a linear manner, both of which should be optimizable.

However, the variable name `asize` gives me pause. It certainly *sounds* like an abbreviation of "array size". If that's the case, then I would 100% recommend using slices instead of array indices. Why? Because array access (`foo[0]`) usually has overhead of bounds checking. I'd write something with slices:

```
let data = vec![0; 10_000_000];
let start_index = 300;

let slice = &data[start_index..];

let left = slice.iter().position(|&i| left_condition(i));
let right = slice.iter().rev().position(|&i| right_condition(i));
```

However, there's only one possible true answer to your question:

Use a profiler

#### Use a profiler

### Use a profiler

## Use a profiler

Only knowing your actual data, your actual implementations of the conditions, *the rest of the code you are running*, etc., can you actually know how fast something will be.

> Therefore it has been a good thing to only have one loop instead of two - in order to avoid search from the beginning again

This is nonintuitive to me, so I'd want to see profiling results that back up the claim.

Comment: Thank you a lot! That was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`cond_left` and `cond_right` are important to answer the performance question. For example, will replacing an index with an iterator help? Not going to tell without knowing what `cond_left` does.

The other concern you have is that `first_edge` and `first_edge_right` are mutable. The proposed [RFC allowing loops to return a value](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/961) could be an elegant way to solve this problem. Right now you could emulate the loop return with a closure:

```
let (_first_edge, _first_edge_right): (i32, i32) = (||{
    let (mut first_edge, mut first_edge_right) = (None, None);
    // ...
    return (first_edge.unwrap(), first_edge_right.unwrap());
})();
```

([In Playground](http://is.gd/G3NCjL)).

Replacing `-1` with `None` will likely make the variable larger. See [Can I use the "null pointer optimization" for my own non-pointer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414068/can-i-use-the-null-pointer-optimization-for-my-own-non-pointer-types).

Splitting this loop into two loops, one getting the `first_edge` and another examining the remaining range to get the `first_edge_right` seems like the right thing to do, but the CPU branch prediction will likely minimize the impact.

Comment: While making the variable an `Option` is likely to make the value larger, it may or may not have any perceived speed difference. I'd certainly use the `Option` first and benchmark it without it. Especially as the size of `i` might already be larger than needed in order to leave room for `-1` as a sentinel value without taking up real values.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is critical to keep looking from both sides simultaneously, I don’t think there is an easy way to avoid having mutable variables.

One thing that can improve readability is to use [`option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) instead of negative numbers. Otherwise the code is fine.

(Another thing you probably could do is to break the loop when the indices meet in the middle, if this means that there is no solution for your problem, but that’s not Rust specific.)