# Can I make size_of::<Option<MyType>>() == size_of::<MyType>() by telling the compiler which values are never inhabited by `MyType`?

Tags: rust, memory-layout

I have this type:

```
struct Foo(u32);
```

The way I use `Foo`, I know that the `u32` inside can never hold the value `u32::max_value()` (but all other values of `u32`). In my application, I need to store *many* instances of `Option<Foo>`. Thus, it would be really helpful if `Option<Foo>` would only occupy 32 bits of memory, and not 64 [as `Option<u32>` does](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=32758247e0c3d8b126e98fd5610767f5&version=stable&mode=debug).

I know that Rust performs this optimization for types like `Option<&T>` where it knows that `&T` can never have the value zero. And I also heard about some nice memory layout optimizations that were merged some time ago.

**Can I somehow inform the compiler about this possible memory layout optimization?**

---

If this is not possible in my exact scenario, would it be possible, if ...

- ... `Foo`'s `u32` would never be `0`? (Maybe it's possible because this is closer to the `Option<&T>` case?)
- ... `Foo`'s `u32` would only use 31 bits? (Maybe we can at least tell Rust that a bit is unused?)

Comment: You can sacrifice an entire byte and then store your number in the remaining 3 bytes as `[u8; 3]` and use accessors to use the value. But then you are limited to maximum values of 0x1000000. it will be a little fiddly still, to get the endianness right etc when reading and writing. To get the full range of values, you'd have to use a smaller type as the first value, and then manually preserve the first byte, _in case_ it has been used in an `Option`. This seems like a crazy amount of effort though, and you'll have no guarantees that it won't break in the future, if a different bit is used.

Comment: Would your `u32` be zero? Or just never `u32::max_value()`? What is the valid range of `Foo`?

Comment: @kennytm I edited my question. So in my real application, `u32::max_value()` is the only value not used by `Foo`. But I'd also be interested in the two other cases I added at the end. @Peter Hall 2^24 values are sadly not enough for me :/

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Can I use the “null pointer optimization” for my own non-pointer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30414068/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.