# Why is the size of Option<f64> 16 bytes on 64bit Linux?

Tags: rust

I tried this on 64bit Linux and it gives `16`:

```
println!("Results: {}", mem::size_of::<Option<f64>>())
```

as I understand, this is because of:

```
pub struct Discriminant<T>(u64, PhantomData<fn() -> T>);
```

What is the sense in a 64bit discriminant? For code written by hand, 256 will be enough, for generated code 2^16 would be a huge number, and I can not even imagine why need 2^32. Why would it use 64 bits for this?

Why does the compiler not optimize it for the `Option` case? 8 bits at the end of the structure should be enough.

Comment: *Why does the compiler not optimize it for the `Option` case* — it **does** optimize it. You just don't yet understand that is optimizing for speed, not memory space.

Comment: See also [Why does an enum require extra memory size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27324821/155423), where a comment addresses your concern.

Comment: Note that the definition of `Discriminant` uses `u64` not because all discriminants are a `u64`, but because it takes a `u64` to store the largest possible discriminant value. In an `Option<u8>`, the size of the discriminant is just 1 (i.e. the size of an `u8`).

Comment: And in `Option<&T>` and `Option<Option<T>>` the discriminant gets embedded into the inner type, taking up no space at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f64` has a 64-bit alignment. Thus a type containing an `f64` needs an alignment of at least 64 bits. The size of a type is guaranteed to be a multiple of its alignment. Since it can't fit in 64 bits, it needs to go up to the next multiple, 128 bits/16 bytes.

Comment: *The size of a type is guaranteed to be a multiple of its alignment* — I don't believe this is strictly true; you can opt into different methods of packing a struct and what is valid varies depends on architecture. I'm not sure if an enum has options for controlling packing though.

Comment: @Shepmaster "More specifically, this is the offset in bytes between successive elements in an array with that item type including alignment padding" implies that it's a multiple, because otherwise the second struct in an array would be unaligned.

Comment: `std::mem::align_of` != `std::mem::size_of`. A single value in a struct or on the stack may have some additional fields packed into its alignment padding.

Comment: @the8472 But `std::mem::size_of::<T>() % std::mem::align_of::<T>() == 0` for all types, right?

Comment: Ah right, I was thinking of the [proposal to distinguish stride and alignment size](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1397), but that's not even an RFC yet.